# Create a right-angled triangular prism in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, geometry, jogl

I'm learning OpenGL (specifically, using JOGL) and I'm trying to create a right-angled triangular prism.  I learned you can create an equilateral prism with `glutWire`/`SolidCylinder` and a a low number of slices (3 for a triangle, obviously).

So I'm wondering if there's some other way to make a prism, or if there's some way to scale an equilateral triangle to turn it into a right triangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I additionally found that (at least in JOGL, no idea about elsewhere) glutSolidCylinder doesn't work correctly - the endplates are drawn at a different rotation than the sides, giving you a very strange looking shape.

So I ended up just making a method that creates a unit-right-triangular prism which you can then rotate and scale as necessary.  There's likely much better ways to do this, so comments are welcome:

```
 private void unitTriangularPrism(GL gl, boolean solid){
    // back endcap
    gl.glBegin(solid ? GL.GL_TRIANGLES : GL.GL_LINES);
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.glEnd();

    // front endcap
    gl.glBegin(solid ? GL.GL_TRIANGLES : GL.GL_LINES);
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 1f, 1f);
    gl.glEnd();

    // bottom
    gl.glBegin(solid ? GL.GL_QUADS : GL.GL_LINES);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glEnd();

    // back
    gl.glBegin(solid ? GL.GL_QUADS : GL.GL_LINES);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 1f, 1f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glEnd();

    // top
    gl.glBegin(solid ? GL.GL_QUADS : GL.GL_LINES);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 1f, 1f);
    gl.glEnd();
}
```

Comment: aside from the fact that all those calls are deprecated in OpenGL 3, and I think you want LINELOOP, not LINES, in the wireframe case (although redundancy probably causes all edges save one to be output anyway), it's a very clear straightforward approach.

Comment: What is the OpenGL 3 equivalent to these calls?